# TypeError: super(<object>).__init__(**kwargs) takes no parameters

Tags: python, kivy

I want to make some android app by using kivy, but it raised me an error:
TypeError: object.**init**() takes no parameters

Here is my code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App

class userInterface(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):    
        super(userInterface,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.btn = Button(text = 'ADD',font_size = '14',
                         color = (55/255.0,54/255.0,65/255.0),size_hint =(.2, .2),pos = (0,0),
                         backgroud_color =  (212/255.0,235/255.0,255/255.0))
        self.add_widget(self.btn)

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return userInterface()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried `super().__init__(**kwargs)`?

Comment: Is there some multiple inheritance going on? Please add the output of `print userInterface.__mro__` to the question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with kivy, but inheriting from a layout class seems fishy. Surely you are meant to use `GridLayout` in a different way?

Comment: The problem is that you passed a property named `backgroud_color` to button which is not there by default. Did you mean `background_color` ?

Comment: What @ApuCoder said. Kristen: In the future, please include a full stacktrace, so that potential helpers don't look at the wrong line of code.